# Best place to see what Stack Exchange site is about?

Tags: support, scope

I want to know where I can  find information about  Stack Exchange site **after joining the site**.

Normaly I would read the site information before I will join it and manage my questions accordingly, but I can't find this information after joining into the site.
**Note** - I know that when I ask a new question I can see the "How to Ask" information window but I want to know if I can get this information before asking a question.

Comment: The tour has a description of a site. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong - but from what I see the tour is there to show me how to use the site and this was not my intention when asking. let me try to be a bit more clear- Let's say that I just joined code review site and by accident didn't read what it was about, now I want to know what the site is all about. (so I can know what kind of question to ask on that site).Where can I find this information about the different stack sites?(tell me if this was not clear)

Comment: But the tour _does_ contain this exact description. For example the [TeX - LaTeX tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) says _“**TeX - LaTeX** is a question and answer site for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, people who love to create well-structured and beautifully typeset documents.”_, which is probably the same description you’d see before joining this site.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted - thank you

Comment: @Xufox The tour is a very bad place to learn what a site is about. Many sites still have a pre-set "example question" about unicorns eating daisies, instead of an actual question from the site. It's a good place to find out how the *Stack Exchange model* works, a terrible place to find out about a *specific site's scope*.

Comment: Is there any other way to learn on the site?

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes, I agree. The tour has useful information, but not nearly *enough* to actually do anything. It's sort of like trying to learn a language with just a dictionary - the dictionary is certainly *helpful*, but you are not likely to actually gain the ability to communicate well in the language without additional materials - a grammar, a leveled textbook, *examples of successful communications*, and *opportunities to practice*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A site's "on topic" page is the best place to learn what sorts of questions are on topic or not.

Here are a couple of examples:

- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://fantasy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

These pages have site-specific content about what's on topic and it can be edited by the moderators on that site to be clear about what they consider welcome or not and many have suggestions on alternate places to ask if the current site is the wrong place.

This information is available to all viewers, whether they've joined the site or not an the URL is easy to create from memory as it's `[sitename].stackexchange.com/help/on-topic` for most of the network with the exception of sites that have their own domains like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: A better way to say the last sentence: "it's `/help/on-topic` on every site".

Comment: Usually the Help link *works* but sometimes they haven't fleshed it out. For example [SQAT](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) basically tells you squat (not much), and [CSE](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says 'see for yourself' (but sort of, this), [Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) hasn't constructed the language for their webpage, much like [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - see where that is going, yes it's operation is still in development. --- Some places cheated on being thorough, low effort.

Comment: @Rob: What you did there… I see it.